# Downloading an unsigned or unproperly signed apk file caused loss of data

Tags: android, apk, unsigned, loss

**Background:**
* I am new to developing for Android but I am a programmer/front-end web developer so I'm not totally new to this sort of thing
* My personal phone is the Samsung Droid Charge, on Verizon - I am unsure if this will really matter or not.

**Problem:**
It seems like I have lost all of my photos and videos, so I'm reaching out to see if anyone knows whether or not for sure I am in trouble, or if there's still hope of recovering this data loss.

**What I believe caused the problem:**
I followed the tutorial on how to make a simple Hello World application, as a first step in learning how to develop using Eclipse. I was unfamiliar, at the time, with signing applications. So, I just used the apk which was in the bin folder of my project. I placed it onto my web server using FileZilla, and pointed my phone browser to the file. It downloaded it, but when I clicked on it, it said something along the lines of "File is too big." or "Application is too big." or "Not enough room to install." or something along those lines. The application was only 28k, but I'm sure that it had something to do with the fact that I did not sign it properly before attempting to use it on my phone.

So - my theory is that since it looked at it as "too big," that it removed other things on my phone which were too big, in order to make room for it. I noticed that my phone suddenly forgot all my ringtone and other sound settings - because it moved them all to my 32GB micro-SD card (which came with the phone). Previously, this data was stored on the internal memory along with my photos and videos. However - I am now not even able to view the files on my internal memory when I go to "My Files" from the apps. Why this would happen, I don't know - it doesn't *seem* like a very good feature to have. A fellow developer at my office mentioned that it may be something Verizon has set in place for some odd reason.

If the photos are still there, which is very possible, I'm not sure how to view them. The gallery app does not recognize any files, and I am otherwise completely unable to look at my internal memory - even using a program called AndExplorer.*

As a new developer for android, this is extremely frustrating. Sure, perhaps I should have backed up my data before testing my app on my own device, but there's absolutely no reason that this should have happened.

I'm sure I can't be the only one who has ever done this. I tried searching for the issue ALL OVER the web AND on stack overflow and was not able to find anything.
Any and all help is greatly appreciated. And I have certainly learned my lesson - I need to back up my stuff before testing *anything*.

*EDIT: It turns out I actually can view the internal memory using AndExplorer, but there doesn't seem to be anything on there, as far as my missing photos and videos.

Answer (score 0):

> I placed it onto my web server using FileZilla, and pointed my phone browser to the file.

Is your Web server configured with the proper MIME type for APK files?

> but I'm sure that it had something to do with the fact that I did not sign it properly before attempting to use it on my phone.

I rather doubt that. You have to explicitly do things to *avoid* signing an APK.

> So - my theory is that since it looked at it as "too big," that it removed other things on my phone which were too big, in order to make room for it.

That seems unlikely. Even if true, this is a question for Verizon/Motorola, not StackOverflow, as only they can help you with end user device issues such as lost data.

> Sure, perhaps I should have backed up my data before testing my app on my own device, but there's absolutely no reason that this should have happened.

It doesn't, in the course of normal development.

> I'm sure I can't be the only one who has ever done this.

You are probably the only person on the face of the planet whose photos, etc. were lost or misplaced as the result of trying to install a hello-world APK.

> And I have certainly learned my lesson - I need to back up my stuff before testing anything.

Then you did not learn your lesson. You need to back up your "stuff", period, unless you are somehow personally invulnerable and believe that this protection will extend to your device. Otherwise, you are as likely as the rest of us to have your phone accidentally get dunked in a toilet, run over by a bakery truck, caught in a fireball triggered by a terrorist attack on a natural gas pipeline, etc. And, in those cases, you would lose your data as well.

In a nutshell, Android development does not typically adversely affect a device, certainly not the mere act of installing an app. Whatever problem you have experienced is due to some combination of events triggering some bug in the Charge (possibly just your individual device).

BTW, the preferred way to test an app on a device is to use the USB cable, then run it from Eclipse on the device itself. FileZilla and downloading from the Web can work with a properly-configured Web server, but that's usually reserved for later in the development process.

Answer (score 0):

CommonsWare, some of what you've said is helpful, but some of it not-so-much. Who says I don't already backup my data? Perhaps I do, and I just hadn't done it in a day? You don't know that much detail about my situation. Maybe I am only missing photos from one day. You can't definitively say I have not learned my lesson. I'll decide if I've learned my lessons or not ;). That should not have been my main focus and for that I apologize.

I'm more interested in *why* this happened than I am interested in getting my data back. I certainly wouldn't want this happening again. If it has nothing to do with "size" or proper signing, what else could possibly ever make something like this happen? Like I said - I am new to developing apps for phones - I can only assume so much using the developer guide provided to me by Android. A lot of the steps assume that the user knows certain things. And perhaps that's my fault and I should start somewhere else for basics.

But I still attest that the issue must have been caused by the app. I did not change anything with mime types, but according to what you're saying, that shouldn't affect things. That should not have had any effect on data loss. Yet, it absolutely, without a doubt *did*.

I've used a program to scan the flash drive to see if it could find any deleted files. That didn't work. So I've pretty much given up on getting the data back. Like I said - my focus should just be to prevent it from happening again.

Comment: PS: it would not allow me to reply to your answer. I think because I was not signed up when I posted my quesiton, and then signed up afterwards. Strange.